# How to create an object reference to a xaml page from App.xaml.cs codebehind?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have a Silverlight 4 Business Project where I have enabled the ASP.NET Authentication/Authorization role information. I would like to pass the currently authenticated user's account information from the app.xaml.cs codebehind to a different XAML page, but I have no idea how that is done, or if it's even possible.

My goal is to databind the IsEnabled property of various buttons of my target XAML page, based on whether the current user is in a particular admin related role or not. The Application_UserLoaded event handler of app.xaml.cs seems to be the safest event handler to initiate this task because it fires only after the user's account information is loaded from the server.

I had previously attempted to retrieve the current user information directly from my target XAML page, but I was never getting the current user information because Application_UserLoaded hadn't finished loading the current user info yet.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
      private void Application_UserLoaded(LoadUserOperation operation)
      {
        // How do you create an object reference to a XAML page from your project solution
        // from this event handler?
      }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, I solved my original issue by raising a custom event handler in the Application_UserLoaded() handler of app.xaml.cs.

I then subscribed to this custom event handler from the codebehind of my specific XAML view page where I needed to databind the IsEnabled property of my various Silverlight controls.

The reason I had to create a custom event handler is because you cannot assume that the security role information will always be ready to reference in the Loaded() event handler of your XAML view page.

I found more information about this specific timing issue at:
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/146631/328217.aspx

cheers,
John

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a reference to your view to accomplish this task. There is a better solution. At first, create a class for the application-wide context with IsAdmin property, and add it to the App's resource dictionary

```
 private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
 {
     this.Resources.Add("GlobalContext", new GlobalContext());
 }
```

Set IsAdmin property in your Application_UserLoaded handler, and bind to it from any of your views

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsAdmin, Source={StaticResource GlobalContext}}"
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks Denis, I'll give it a try when I get back from vacation and be sure to mark your answer as the correct one, if I verify it works. Cheers, John

Comment: After a bit of close line by line debugging, it appears that I'm occasionally seeing some timing issues between my App.xaml.cs Application_UserLoaded() event handler and my View.xaml.cs LayoutRoot_Loaded() event handler. It appears that my view's LayoutRoot_Loaded() event handler, on occasion, gets fired BEFORE my Application_UserLoaded() event handler, which is responsible for getting the current user's role information. Due to this timing issue, the Role information isn't yet available for use in the view page where I want to databind my controls. Any thoughts on this issue? thanks...